# Convert Varchar2(24-JAN-2016) to number (YYYYMMDD

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, datastage

I want to convert **varchar2(24-JAN-16) to number(20160124)** in Oracle and Datastage.

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why? Why not convert it to date?

Comment: Let me be a bit more assertive. You really **should** convert it to DATE.

Comment: To be clear, I'm with @BobC 100%. But if you really have a legitimate use case for this, then something like this could help. `SELECT TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('24-JAN-16','DD-MON-RR'), 'YYYYMMDD')) FROM dual;`

Comment: And if you do have a legitimate used case, please share it :)

Comment: @HepC you should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @Bohemian I always hesitate posting an answer that I hope isn't the final solution. Even though it answers the exact question, I'm hoping the solution is that a date is acceptable.

Comment: And incidently, the subject and the question are subtly different :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a firm requirement - and you can't just use this as a date - then the following SQL will accomplish taking a string, and converting it the the number you want.

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('24-JAN-16','DD-MON-RR'), 'YYYYMMDD')) FROM dual;
```

Comment: Thank you all your replies.

I have to convert to number, because the DW has all field with day_code as a number (pe, 20170313).

I know this situation is not desirable, but I am just following my company's requirement.